# No signature of method error for SampleResult.setFailure() in jmeter webdriver sampler

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I am getting an issue in one of the webdriver samplers - "sampleResult.setFailure - Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.setFailure() is applicable for argument types: (Boolean) values: [true]"

Following is the groovy code snippet I have used for the jp@gc webdriver sampler.
WDS.log.info is working as expected. But I can't make the sampler fail if the condition fails, due to the above error. Can you please help me identify the issue?

```
var compareWord = tempXpath.getText();
  if (compareWord.contains("$value")) {
      WDS.log.info("The value is as expected");
  }
  else{
      WDS.sampleResult.setFailure(true);
      WDS.log.info("The field not matching for: " + "$value");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you got information regarding existence of `SampleResult.setFailure()` function, my expectation is that from generative AI.

If you look into [JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) you will see that the function doesn't exist and if you look into [JMeter source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter) you will see that it has never existed.

Correct function is [SampleResult.setSuccessful()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setSuccessful(boolean)) so instead of this one:

```
WDS.sampleResult.setFailure(true);
```

you should use something like:

```
WDS.sampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
```

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I got the function name from one of the discussion forums. Since the name sounded so normal, didn't check the authenticity of it. Thanks for pointing it out. It worked